# Is there a way to debug the ModelBinding?

Tags: servicestack, model-binding

I am using ServiceStack and am having difficulty with one of my Request DTOs.  One of the properties of type `int` is always coming through as `0` even though I can see it set correctly in the request.

**Is there a method of debugging the ModelBinding process within ServiceStack?**

Comment: I have resolved my problem (simple error), but the question still stands.  I would love to have some visibility into the Model Binding process.